# break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch Android Grid View

Tags: android, gridview

I am working on android app with grid view and `OnItemClickListener`
But I get this weird error

> break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch

How can I fix this and why is this happening?

```
int i = 1;


gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:

             if(i == 1){
                 if(mp!=null)
                    {
                        mp.release();
                        mp=null;
                    }

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Sadrzaj.this,
                            R.raw.s10nicetone);
                    mp.start();
                 i = 2;
           } else if (i==2){
               mp.pause();
             mp.seekTo(0);
                i = 1;

           }
        break;
            case 1:
             if(i == 1){
                 if(mp!=null)
                    {
                        mp.release();
                        mp=null;
                    }

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Sadrzaj.this,
                            R.raw.s1beautiful);
                    mp.start();
                 i = 2;
           } else if (i==2){
             mp.pause();
             mp.seekTo(0);
            }
                i = 1;

        }
            break;



    }
});

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the break outside of switch

```
i = 1;
} // switch brace ends here
break; // outside of the ending brace
```

The break should be within the ending brace like

```
i = 1;
break; 
}
```

Edit:

To make it clear

```
 switch (position) { // switch brace open
    case 0:
        if(i == 1){ // if brace 1 open
             if(mp!=null)
              {        // if brace 2 open
                    mp.release();
                    mp=null; 
              }        // if brace 2 close
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(Sadrzaj.this,R.raw.s10nicetone);
                mp.start();
                 i = 2;
         } // if brace 1 close
         else if (i==2){ // else brace open
           mp.pause();
           mp.seekTo(0);
           i = 1;
          } // else brace closed
    break; // break here is fine
        case 1:
             if(i == 1){ // if brace 1 open
               if(mp!=null)
                {         // if brace 2 open
                    mp.release();
                    mp=null;
                }          // if brace 2 closed

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(Sadrzaj.this,R.raw.s1beautiful);
                mp.start();
             i = 2;
            }   // if brace 1 closed
            else if (i==2){  // else brace opened
               mp.pause();
               mp.seekTo(0);
            }   // else brace closed
            i = 1;

          } // switch brace closed here
        break;  //then you have the break. should be before the closing break
```

Comment: I tried with your code, and 1st Media Player won't play.

Comment: @Sabroan what i suggested if for case 1 where the break should be before the end of switch closing brace

Comment: O yeah now I get it, bit tired :D Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you fixed you code format you would see that your last break is outside of your switch statement. Thats why its always good to write clean code